# align three time series in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following time series:
[image]

I would like to align the signals only after time = 800, based on having the  minimum points aligned.

I have tried the following to align two of the signals in pandas:

```
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
s1 = Series(vec1)
s2 = Series(vec2)
s3 = s1.align(s2,join='inner')

s1 = np.array(s1)
s2 = np.array(s2)
s3 = np.array(s3)

plt.plot(t,s1)
plt.plot(t,s2)
plt.plot(t,s3)
plt.show()
```

Which shows the aligned signals exactly as the original form. Any recommendations on how to achieve the minimum alignment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find and align the minima:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #making toy data
x = np.arange(0, 2, .05)

s = []
s.append(np.sin(x*3))
s.append(np.cos(x*4+0.3))
s.append(np.sin(x)*np.exp(2-x)*-1)
plt.clf()
plt.plot(x, s[0], x, s[1], x, s[2])
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

[image]

```
mindexes = [i.argmin() for i in s]  #finding the minima
shifts = mindexes - min(mindexes)

def shifted(shift, x, s):
    if shift == 0:   #x[:-0] was not what I wanted.
        return x, s
    else:
        return x[:-1*shift], s[shift:]

for i in (0,1,2):
    px, py = shifted(shifts[i], x, s[i]) 
    plt.plot(px, py)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the line shifts = mindexes - min(mindexes) gives the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'map' and 'int'. Could you maybe explain what you did here?

Comment: I can't remember what I did in 2015, but replacing the map with a list comprehension fixes it on my machine. Thank you for the bug report -- is it fixed for you now?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit crude, but why not implement a while loop?
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

```
# assuming you are shifting s2 to the left
# cut off at 800 s
s1 = s1[s1.index>=800]
s2 = s2[s2.index>=800]

while s2.index[s2==s2.min()]>s1.index[s1==s1.min()]:
    s2 = s2[801:]
    s2.index = np.arange(800,800 + s2.shape[0])
```